Points where $f(z)=\overline{\operatorname{Log}(z)} - |z|^2 $ is complex differentiable.
Using Wirtinger derivatives we obtain:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline z} \left( \overline{\operatorname{Log}} \right)=\overline{ \left(\frac{\partial \operatorname{Log}}{\partial z} \right) } = \overline{ \left(\frac{1}{z} \right) }=\frac{1}{\overline z}$$
And:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline z} \left( |z|^2 \right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline z} \left( z \overline z \right)=z$$
Therefore:
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline z}= \frac{1}{\overline z}-z=0 \iff |z|^2=1$$
So $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline z} = 0$ iff $z \in \mathbb D = \{z\in \mathbb C :|z|=1 \}.$ As $\operatorname{Log}$ is not continuous in $(-\infty, 0]$, we need to remove $z=-1$. So: $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline z} = 0 \iff z=e^{i\theta}, \theta \in (-\pi,\pi)$$
Now I must show that $f$ is continuously differentiable in the real sense in order to conclude. But I'm having trouble checking if $\overline{\operatorname{Log}}$ is continuously differentiable as a real function over $\mathbb D \setminus \{-1\}$. I have yet to see in class theorems regarding relations between complex differentiablity and continuous differentiablity in the real sense, so I'm pretty sure I have to use the definitions. I know that $\operatorname{Log}$ is analytic, and I know that $z \mapsto \overline z$ is not analytic, and that's pretty much it, and obviously the Cauchy-Riemann equations theorem, but that's pretty much it...
Would appreciate any help, thank you!

One approach is to take the partial derivatives of your function with respect to $z$ for $|\arg z|<\pi$ where the logarithm is continuous. You may verify that this gives just $-\overline{z}$ (note that $\overline{\log(z)}=\log(\overline{z})$). Thus your complete expression for the differential is
$df=-\overline{z}\space dz+\left(\dfrac1{z}-\overline{z}\right)d\overline{z},|\arg z|<\pi.$
You already eliminated the $d\overline{z}$ term by putting in $|z|=1$. Now put $\overline{z}=1/z$ (why?) into the remaining $z$ term and identify a total derivative that is defined everywhere on the cut unit circle you identified:
$df=-dz/z\implies df/dz=-1/z,|z|=1,|\arg z|<\pi.$
Now let's see wharlt happens if we directly apply the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Start with extracting the real and imagibary parts. For $|z|^2$ we have just
$|z|^2=(x^2+y^2)+i(0).$
For the logarithm it's a little trickier. We can use the familiar expression for the real part, but the imaginary part has to be a modified inverse tangent function definable over all of $|\arg z|<\pi$:
$\overline{\log(z)}=\frac12\log(x^2+y^2)-2\arctan\left(\dfrac{y}{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)$
The arctangent function given above matches $\arctan(y/x)$ for $|\arg z|<\pi/2$, which can be proved using $\tan(\frac12\theta)=\sin\theta/(\cos(\theta+1)$, but also avoids a zero denominator for all of $|\arg z|<\pi$.
So we take the difference and in the C-R criteria we have:
$u=\frac12\log(x^2+y^2)-(x^2+y^2)$
$v=-2\arctan\left(\dfrac{y}{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)$
I will set prove the condition $\partial u/\partial x=\partial v/\partial y)$. The second condition $\partial u/\partial y=-\partial v/\partial x)$ proceeds similarly and is left to the reader.
So
$\partial u/\partial x=\dfrac12\left(\dfrac{2x}{x^2+y^2}\right)-2x=-x$
For the derivative of the arctangent, we use
$d[\arctan(u/v)]=\dfrac{(v)(du)-(u)(dv)}{u^2+v^2},$
which is established by combining the Chain Rule with the Quotient Rule. Thus
$\partial v/\partial y = 2\dfrac{(x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2})(1)-(y/\sqrt{x^2+y^2})(y)}{y^2+(x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^2}$
Only $x^2+y^2=1$ is in scope, so
$\partial v/\partial y = 2\dfrac{x+1-(1-x^2)}{1-x^2+(x+1)^2}=-2x(1+x)/[2(1+x)]=x,$
where we requite $1+x\not=0$ along with $x^2+y^2=1$ and thus the condition $|\arg z|<\pi$ emerges naturally. Thus
$\partial u/\partial x=\partial v/\partial y=x$
as required. Note that this agrees with the real part of the derivative $1/z$ found earlier when $|z|=1$. Similarly if one tests  $\partial u/\partial y=-\partial v/\partial x)$, one will find that the common value $-y$ agrees with the imaginary part if $1/z$.

Thank you! I'm not sure how to verify the partial derivative with respect to $z$ is $\bar z$ - why is $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} (\overline{\operatorname{Log}}) = 0$?

The (principal branch of the) logarithm is equal to $\log(\overline{z})$, which has no terms depending on $z$ as opposed to $\overline{z}$.

Oh I see. So just one more question - in order to show $f$ is differentiabe on the cut unit circle don't I also need to show $f$ is continuously differentiable in the real sense? We've only seen in class that if it is continoulsy differentiable in the real sense, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{df}{dz}$ agree, not the other way around
